# How to handle categorical and non-euclidean data in GMM model?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, gmm

What transformation measure needs to be taken for "only categorical" and "mix of numeric and categorical" and "Non-Euclidean data" for Gaussian mixture models? Does GMM only work on numerical data?

Answer (score 0):

**Gaussian** Mixture Modeling obviously only works for numerical data, because the Gaussian distribution is over R.

However you can essentially do the same with other distributions such as multinomial or binomial; even mixed (at least if you assume feature independence it's trivial).